# Changing image size Javascript depending on screensize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Am using bootstrap, which for some reason means whenever i try the `@media (min-height: 1000px)` there is no response from the image class.

I would like to run a javascript that resizes the image when the screen height gets above a certain size. (Lets say 1000 px)

the best code I have found is this

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        if ($(window).height() >= 710) {
            $("img").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("logo1.png", "logo2.png"));
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

However when i replace src with width, and change the corresponding values of logo1.png and logo2.png to 500 and 800 nothing happens.

Any pointers using Javascript very much appreciated.

I tried this in CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) and (min-height: 1000px) {
 .iphonegangster {
  min-width: 950px;
  height: auto;
 }
```

Comment: if you're doing a mobile site, you should start with what you want your image size to be first, then when you get under 1000px, set it to the next level and so forth for the next sizes

Comment: How would you do that? using the JS?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JS, you can use CSS media queries with image background. Ex., `<i role=image class=img1/>`.  Using CSS media query pick image based on screen size.

Comment: is that different to what I have done above? setting a class and giving that class a min-width (of the image) where i specify a min-height in the @media screen and? - either way I failed to make it work